# MongoDB - Sorting on multiple fields that may or may not be Arrays (“cannot sort with keys that are parallel arrays”)

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, sorting

I have an issue with indexing and sorting of fields with unknown type in my use case. This means they may be an Array in one document, but the same field in another document could be something else.

Now, you may know Mongo doesn’t allow indexing or sorting on multiple Array fields it gives the following error if you try : “cannot sort with keys that are parallel arrays”

As an exemple to explain this post I’ll use the following index : `{a:1,b:1}`
Keep in mind field a and field b can be of any type in this exemple (Object, Array, number, string, Date etc…) and the type can be different between documents.

In this exemple if I try to insert the following document it works :
`{a:1, b:2}`
`{a:[1,2,3],b:"hi"}`

But if I try to insert a document like this :
`{a:[1,2,3], b:["a","b","c"]}`

I get an error.

I don’t know what to do to fix this issue, and this restriction makes no sense.
[Related issue on MongoDB Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-826)

I absolutely need in my use case to be able to sort on arbitrary fields, and I’ve yet to come up with a workaround that makes sense and won’t impact performance too much.

The workarounds I came up with :

- Create a copy of all fields for sorting purposes where Arrays are converted to strings or another format (Obviously this is very bad because it duplicates all data)
  exemple : {a:1, a_sort:1, b:[1,2,3], b_sort:"[1,2,3]"} and the index : {a_sort:1, b_sort:1}
- Replace the $sort aggregation stage with a $function aggregation performing a custom sort, this is also very bad because we lose all benefits from indexes and the optimization on the $limit stage (limit stage optimization can be somewhat emulated in the function by returning immediately false in the filter, but it won’t be as efficient as the mongo one)
- Never store array store an object with keys "entry_0", "entry_1", "entry_2" and convert into an array in application code, also very bad because we lose access to $push, $pull, $in and other operators that work on arrays and it adds work to the application.

(Note that I don't actually need to sort the arrays as arrays, they could be converted to string as long as the order is logical and doesn't break other value types, I just wish there was a flag or something to tell mongo to sort arrays by their JSON string instead just so it doesn't break other data types)

Any ideas or suggestions ?